# Component registration issue using MediatR and Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, cqrs, mediatr

I'm building a CQRS based .Net Core 2.1 application using Autofac and MediatR.

```
public class MediatorModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        var mediatrOpenTypes = new[]
        {
            typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
            typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
        };

        foreach (var mediatrOpenType in mediatrOpenTypes)
        {
            builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CreateMessageCommand.GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .AsClosedTypesOf(mediatrOpenType)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>)).As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RequestPreProcessorBehavior<,>)).As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));

        builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx =>
        {
            var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return t => c.Resolve(t);
        });

    }
}
```

When i feed the command to mediator, it works perfectly fine and the Handle() on the command handler gets executed.

```
var cmd = new CreateMessageCommand("Foo")
_mediator.Send(cmd)
```

Things don't go well when i execute it this way

```
var cmd = new CreateMessageCommand("Foo")
var req = new IdentifiedCommand<CreateMessageCommand, bool>(cmd, @event.Id);
await _mediator.Send(req);
```

**Exception:**

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Backend.MessageService.Commands.IdentifiedCommand`2[Backend.MessageService.Commands.CreateMessageCommand,System.Boolean],System.Boolean]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples. ---> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[[Backend.MessageService.Commands.IdentifiedCommand`2[[Backend.MessageService.Commands.CreateMessageCommand, Backend.MessageService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Backend.MessageService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

```
public class IdentifiedCommand<T, R> : IRequest<R>
    where T : IRequest<R>
{
    public T Command { get; }
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public IdentifiedCommand(T command, Guid id)
    {
        Command = command;
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class IdentifiedCommandHandler<T, R> :
    IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<T, R>, R>
    where T : IRequest<R> {...}
```

May i know what's missing?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1529#issuecomment-735232712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this resolved my issue.

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(IdentifiedCommandHandler<CreateMessageCommand, bool>))
    .As<IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<CreateMessageCommand, bool>, bool>>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: How can you make this work for any type of commands, and not just CreateMessageCommand ? You have to register every command you want to be Identified one by one?

Answer (score 3):

The command you are sending to MediatR is of type `IdentifiedCommand<CreateMessageCommand, bool>`. So MediatR will look for a handler with the type `IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<CreateMessageCommand, bool>, bool>>`.

The DI container will usually do that by first looking for an exact match, and then it considers open generic type registrations. In this case, it will look for an `IRequestHandler<,>` registration, for which it would insert the type arguments `IdentifiedCommand<CreateMessageCommand, bool>`, and `bool`. However, your command handler does not implement `IRequestHandler<T, R>`, instead it implements `IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<T, R>, R>` which is not a suitable fit for this. So the DI container does not find a handler and will raise that error.

In order for this to work, you will have to implement the type in the way the DI container will look for it. So you will have to implement `IRequestHandler<T, R>` instead.

Unfortunately, this also means that you cannot have a type-safe way to accept an `IdentifiedCommand<T, R>` in the handler. Instead, you just get a `T` request which you will have to work with.